# C# mongodb BigInteger serialization

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following object:

```
public abstract class RichPerson{
    public string name;
    public BigInteger money;
}
```

I want money attribute to be stored in mongo as a string. But when selecting the documents from mongo, I want to serialize money attribute to BigInteger type with some kind of constructor.

How do I tell mongo to do that?

Comment: May I suggest that BigInteger is not the best datatype to store money?

Comment: I have posted a solution now. I dont know why people would downvote a question like that or have worries about BigInteger not being an appropriate type. It is obviously a simplified example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering here is the solution. You have to specify custom [BsonSerializer] for the money field. I hope this is the right approach.

```
public class RichPerson
{
    public string name;
    [BsonSerializer(typeof(MySerializer))]
    public BigInteger money;
}

public class MySerializer : SerializerBase<BigInteger>
{
    public override BigInteger Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        string val = context.Reader.ReadString();
        return BigInteger.Parse(val);
    }

    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, BigInteger value)
    {
        context.Writer.WriteString(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tell MongoDB, this is a string and it will do the rest

```
public class RichPerson 
   {
      public string name {get; set;}
      [BsonRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.String)]
      public double money {get; set}
   }
```

Edited the answer to show the model I used to make it work double, long or decimal data type. MongoDB does not know biginteger, sorry mate.

1. Model

[image]

2. Save it as string

[image]

3. Return the type in the model (decimal, long, or double)

[image]

Comment: I get an error: A serializer of type 'BsonClassMapSerializer<BigInteger>' is not configurable using an attribute of type 'BsonRepresentationAttribute'.